# Most performant way of deducing whether int attribute of field annotations in class are consecutive?

Tags: java

I have a class that contains N instance fields and each field may be annotated with a custom annotation which contains an attribute named 'index' which is just an integer value.  I need to extract all of the annotated field names from the class and order them in an array according to the specified index attribute value.  The key part though is that the index values cannot be negative, duplicated and they must eventually form a contiguous series with no missing indices.  So if the class had 6 annotated fields it would only be valid if they had been declared with indices 0 .. 5

So I have an initial loop which processes the fields in the class and checks whether the field is annotated with the custom annotation.  That part is easy, but as I don't know upfront how many fields in the supplied class will be annotated with the custom annotation I cannot create a suitably sized array to hold all of the elements upfront.

I also then will have to iterate back over the populated array to check for missing indices.

Is there a quicker way that does not involve iterating twice and continually creating new arrays to hold the elements?

I am more interested from a purist point how you would tackle this if performance was paramount.

Comment: (1) Why does this annotation not have a parameter `index` (or `value`)? (2) Why aren't you just using a list?

Comment: Question reworded as wasn't very clear.